# Moving two rectangles with transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using the following code, I can move two rectangles together with a transition, but after moving the two rectangles together, one of the rectangles moves from bottom to top again.

```js
var rectangles = document.getElementsByClassName("rectangle");

for (var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
  var rectangle = rectangles[i];
  var upButton = rectangle.getElementsByClassName("up")[0];
  var downButton = rectangle.getElementsByClassName("down")[0];

  upButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    moveFile(this.parentNode, "up");
  });

  downButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    moveFile(this.parentNode, "down");
  });
}

function moveFile(currentRectangle, direction) {
  var siblingRectangle = direction === "up" ? currentRectangle.previousElementSibling : currentRectangle.nextElementSibling;

  if (siblingRectangle) {
    currentRectangle.classList.add(direction === "up" ? "move-up" : "move-down");
    siblingRectangle.classList.add(direction === "up" ? "move-down" : "move-up");

    setTimeout(function() {
      if (direction === "up") {
        currentRectangle.parentNode.insertBefore(currentRectangle, siblingRectangle);
      } else {
        currentRectangle.parentNode.insertBefore(siblingRectangle, currentRectangle);
      }
      currentRectangle.classList.remove(direction === "up" ? "move-up" : "move-down");
      siblingRectangle.classList.remove(direction === "up" ? "move-down" : "move-up");
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: solid rgb(255, 126, 126);
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-up {
  transform: translateY(-120px);
}

.move-down {
  transform: translateY(120px);
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle">
    <div>1</div>
    <button class="button up">Up</button>
    <button class="button down">Down</button>
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <div>2</div>
    <button class="button up">Up</button>
    <button class="button down">Down</button>
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <div>3</div>
    <button class="button up">Up</button>
    <button class="button down">Down</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can test the above code. As you will see, after the rectangles are moved, one of the rectangles moves up again.
How to remove this extra movement?

Comment: If you could add the related HTML and CSS for this that would be a huge help for anyone trying to answer your question.  Edit your question and create a snippet using the button that looks like `[<>]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Used CSS variables to calculate the travel distance of the rectangles instead of eyeballing them. you hard-coded it to 120px, but since you have a border as well, you need to move 123px instead.
- Moved the CSS transition definition into the transition classes (in order to avoid animation on the transition end)
- Added event listener to the container instead of each button since the animation is on the list and not a single item. This doesn't do much for a constant list of 3 items, but if you have A LOT of elements, it might have better performance to listen to a single element. This is also the reason I listen to transition end events only when necessary (my preference. You can do it the way you did ofc)
- After knowing the direction and target element, transition both elements based on the direction
- After the transition finishes, make sure we remove all transition classes and move the elements in the DOM (should not be animated since we removed the transition CSS property). Instead of using `setTimeout`, I'm listening to [the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event) `transitionend` to reset everything with the new order only after the animation finishes.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
container.onclick = function(event) {
  const targetElement = event.target;
  const isButtonElement = targetElement.matches('button');
  const isUpAction = targetElement.classList.contains('up');
  const isDownAction = targetElement.classList.contains('down');

  if (isButtonElement) {
    const isFirstElement = !targetElement.parentNode.previousElementSibling;
    const isLastElement = !targetElement.parentNode.nextElementSibling;

    // ignore edge cases
    if ((isUpAction && isFirstElement) || (isDownAction && isLastElement)) {
      return;
    }

    if (isUpAction) {
      const elementToMove = targetElement.parentNode;
      const elementToReplace = elementToMove.previousElementSibling;
      // listen to animation finish ONCE to move elements
      elementToMove.addEventListener("transitionend", onTransitionFinished(
        'up',
        elementToMove,
        elementToReplace
      ), {
        once: true
      });

      // move target up and sibling down
      elementToMove.classList.add('move-up');
      elementToReplace.classList.add('move-down');
    }

    if (isDownAction) {
      const elementToMove = targetElement.parentNode;
      const elementToReplace = elementToMove.nextElementSibling;
      // listen to animation finish ONCE to move elements
      elementToMove.addEventListener("transitionend", onTransitionFinished(
        'down',
        elementToMove,
        elementToReplace
      ), {
        once: true
      });

      // move target down and sibling up
      elementToMove.classList.add('move-down');
      elementToReplace.classList.add('move-up');
    }
  }
};

function onTransitionFinished(dir, elementToMove, elementToReplace) {
  return function(event) {
    // clean up all transition classes
    document
      .querySelectorAll('.rectangle')
      .forEach((rectangle) => {
        rectangle.classList.remove('move-up');
        rectangle.classList.remove('move-down');
      });

    // insert in the right place based on direction after transition finished
    if (dir === 'up') {
      elementToReplace.parentNode.insertBefore(elementToMove, elementToReplace);
    } else {
      elementToMove.parentNode.insertBefore(elementToReplace, elementToMove);
    }
  };
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
  --rectangle-height: 100px;
  --rectangle-border: 1px;
  --rectangle-margin: 10px;
  --travel-distance: calc(var(--rectangle-height) + 2*var(--rectangle-border) + 2*var(--rectangle-margin));
}

.rectangle {
  width: 150px;
  height: var(--rectangle-height);
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: var(--rectangle-border) solid rgb(255, 126, 126);
  margin: var(--rectangle-margin);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

.move-up {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  /* MOVED THIS HERE! */
  transform: translateY(calc(-1*var(--travel-distance)));
}

.move-down {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  /* AND HERE! */
  transform: translateY(var(--travel-distance));
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle">
    <div>1</div>
    <button class="button up">Up</button>
    <button class="button down">Down</button>
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <div>2</div>
    <button class="button up">Up</button>
    <button class="button down">Down</button>
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <div>3</div>
    <button class="button up">Up</button>
    <button class="button down">Down</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Personally - and this is a personal choice - I'd prefer to replace your `isButtonElement = targetElement.tagName === 'BUTTON'` with `isButtonElement = targetElement.matches('button');` (this is mostly because I absolutely hate that `tagName` is always uppercase, which I fundamentally dislike in HTML too, when uppercase is used). Reference: [`matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).

Comment: @DavidThomas nice! changed :-)

Comment: Thanks for working on it. It seems that there is an easier solution to debug the initial code. This is important, why only the second rectangle moves twice and how can we stop it or stop the animation from continuing? Or why, when the "down" button is clicked, the first rectangle moves under it instead of moving over the second rectangle?!

Comment: @FirstLast If I need to guess it's most likely the fact you have your `tranisition` definition on your main CSS class `.ractangle` instead of the transition classes. Also removing the classes using a `setTimeout` is not that great since the animation can go out-of-sync. So those are the 2 areas I would investigate in the original code first

Comment: Problem found. Only by delete `transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;` into `.rectangle` and add `transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;` into `.move-up` & `.move-down,` the code will run correctly. simply!